# Pylance "layers" is not a known member of "None" when calling model.layers in Tensorflow v2?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, pylance

I'm getting this Pylance warning in the 2nd code line when I call `model.layers` and I have no idea why.
Yet, I can't find any questions regardin the same issue.
Although it is just a warning, I'd like to understant it.
Does anyone have any solution to this?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model
    
model = load_model('my_model_final.h5', compile=False)
for layer in model.layers[0:20]:
        layer.trainable = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Pylance is telling you "It is possible for model to be None, and None does not have a method called layers."  This can be solved with several methods, the most common being to wrap it in an if statement with the condition that model is not None or to simply assert that model is not None.

```
model = load_model('my_model_final.h5', compile=False)
if model is not None:
    for layer in model.layers[0:20]:
        layer.trainable = False
```

or

```
model = load_model('my_model_final.h5', compile=False)
assert model is not None
for layer in model.layers[0:20]:
    layer.trainable = False
```